# Chilkat: Error while requesting remote signature

Tags: delphi, docusignapi, chilkat, intraweb

Trying to achieve this using Delphi 10 Seattle/Intraweb 15.0.23

Tried the sample code and received a 401 error. Have installed chilkat and unlocked chilkat API for 30 day trial run.

Used Global unlock code from here
https://www.example-code.com/delphidll/global_unlock.asp

Using Docusign code from here
https://www.example-code.com/delphidll/docusign_request_signature_via_email.asp

Thanks

Response Received

Response Body:
{}
Response Status Code = 401
Response Header:
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 249
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: e863f1f6-253b-437a-a4e8-fd1815d6b262
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 19:15:52 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding

Failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an authentication issue. Not sure how you obtained your accessToken, but the error is "The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."
You need to ensure you obtain your accessToken from the correct endpoint and that is for the correct account. If you are using JWT - check your RSA private key.
Also, the delphi code is a bit outdated and uses API 2.0, you should use 2.1

Comment: Appreciate your response. I am using JWT and wasn't aware that I had to use the RSA private key.